# How to deploy an Azure Go web app via git push with private repositories as dependencies?

Tags: azure, go, azure-web-app-service, kudu

What would be the proper way to deploy a Go app to Azure that have private GitHub repositories as dependencies? Here's the current error from Kudu:

```
Resolving dependencies
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/my/privaterepo
  D:\local\Temp\8d315fa89272e69\gopath\src\github.com\my\privaterepo
Cloning into 'D:\local\Temp\8d315fa89272e69\gopath\src\github.com\my\privaterepo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Bad file descriptor
package github.com/my/privaterepo/pkg1: exit status 128
package github.com/my/privaterepo/pkg2: cannot find package $GOROOT)

Building Go app to produce exe file
azureapp\file.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/my/privaterepo/pkg1" 
in any of:
    D:\Program Files\Go\1.5.1\src\github.com\my\privaterepo\pkg1 (from $GOROOT)
```

I was previously deploying via FTP with `web.config`'s HttpPlatformHandler entry. But using git push is quicker especially for non-Windows team members.

Thanks

Comment: Try to vendor your dependencies using a tool like godep.

Comment: yep, as @Not_a_Golfer suggest. vendoring should solve your issue where you have a copy of the dependency in your source code. Azure is support Go ver1.5+, you should be able to use the latest build-in vendor feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Not_a_Golfer and @Xiaomin said, vendoring the dependencies worked, here's what I did:

1. Turned the env variable on locally `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1`
2. Installed `godep` => `go get github.com/tools/godep`
3. Making sure your app is passing a `go build` & `go test`
4. Ran `godep save` this copied all dependencies to ./vendor
5. On my Azure web app, I also set the environment variable `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1`
6. git pushed and voila.

At first I did not set the environment variable on my Azure app, so the dependency resolver was not looking in ./vendor, turning it to 1 fixed everything.